# Pass sql Blob to the client side

Tags: hibernate, gwt

I want to display image to the client side , but the problem is my image is stored in     database in Blob format .

Can u help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far...? You'll probably want to create a page that loads the image from the database and serves it ala  http://bit.ly/c40sON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/06/base64-ie/

< img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////
wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4ML
wWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw=="
alt="Base64 encoded image" width="150" height="150"/>

Comment: *Do not* send images to the browser like this. There are lots of reasons why this is a terrible idea. The link, however, does explain how to do this properly (through a handler)